# what could be wrong with my code, its telling wrong information added yet its correct information. thanks php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","system_database");

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

        $Username = trim($_POST['Username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);


        // encrypt password before submiting it
        $password_encrypted = crypt($password, 'is'); // "is" is the salt


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username = '$Username' AND password='$password_encrypted'";
        $query = $con -> query($sql);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($result == true){


            header ("location: report.php");

        } else {
            echo "username or password wrong";
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Post the exact error.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: See what the [PHP Manual says about `crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Comment: no idea since there's code missing and schema/values.

Comment: _Small Note_ `crypt()` and the correct `password_hash()` create a HASH. Hashing is not encryption

Comment: Its also almost impossible to know whats wrong with the code unless we can see the way you hashed and saved the password in the first plasce presumably in the registration script

Answer (score 0):

add like this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","system_database");
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $Username = trim($_POST['Username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    if(!empty($Username) && !empty($password)){
        $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
        // encrypt password before submiting it
        $password_encrypted = crypt($password, 'is'); // "is" is the salt
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username = '{$Username}' AND password='{$password_encrypted}'";
        if($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                mysqli_free_result($result);
                header("Location: report.php");         
            }else{
                echo "username or password wrong";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "username or password not found";
    }
}
?>
```